# using convex hull for count object in image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HUzN.jpg)I have the image after thresholding and some kind of processing and I know we have to pass Points to the convexHull am just still trying and this as example as lables of region 3

```
ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(Cells) 
Points=zip(*np.where(labels == 3))
Points=np.asarray(Points)
print (Points)
ContPoints=cv2.convexHull(np.asarray(Points))
print (ContPoints)


cv2.imshow('out',Cells)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

TypeError: points data type = 17 is not supported

what part should I change as the Cells image is already binary image

`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` this for image type

Comment: can you post the sample image you are working with?

Comment: I linked the image ....already done as I saw preprocessing listed above and I tried change to np.array it give me  
error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp:137: error: (-215) total >= 0 && (depth == 5 || depth == 4) in function convexHull